# sql query for reading all the rows in a table by sorting the column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has around 5 columns, I want to arrange them in alphabetical order and display all the records present in that table.

Sample Table as below .

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Expected Output is :

```
|ADDRESS   |AGE| ID| NAME     |  SALARY |
|Ahmedabad |32 | 1 | Ramesh   | 2000.00 |
|Ahmedabad |32 | 1 | Ramesh   | 2000.00 |
|Delhi     |25 | 2 | Khilan   | 1500.00 |
|Kota      |23 | 3 | Kaushik  | 2000.00 |
|Mumbai    |25 | 4 | Chaitali | 6500.00 |
```

Comment: Add the table structure in the question (and not a link) and provide exact output required

Comment: You could just research the SQL to perform the ordering on that site, the answer is there and it's easier to find than asking a question on SO: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp.

Comment: I see you are RTFMing, just keep reading...

Comment: By alphabetical, do you mean you want the columns to go alphabetical? Or the data in each column to go alphabetical?

Comment: I have shared the expected out. the sorted order w.r.t column names arranged alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need order based on `column_names` not on `column_values`.

Please follow the below steps:

1. Find the list of columns in your table,`information_schema.columns` is the (ANSI standard) view ,for oracle it is `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.Use a cursor to fetch the records in comma separated way `order by column_name ASC`.For eg in your case ADDRESS,AGE,ID,NAME,SALARY
2. Create a dynamic query using this cursor record to fetch the output.

**P.S** I have never tried this as there is no need to find output based on sorting of column names,if it is a fixed table then you can hardcode the column name.

Comment: I agree with your Approach Gaurav. This is possible in that. I require to migrate data from SQL server to Oracle. Hence planning to convert all the data into .csv than importing into .csv file. If you can share me the query for this than that would be great help.

Comment: @SanjayJain:Why you need to migrate data from sql server ,i have already written that use `information_schema.columns` table ,which is common for all the database ,it is ANSI standard ,so you can use this schema in your sql server to retrieve column list .

Comment: We require this for a data migration from SQL to Oracle. This is one of the step involved in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDERBY column_That_u_want_to_Order By ASC

Eg: As per your Table

```
Select * From Customers
ORDER BY CustomerName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this query :

```
SELECT [ADDRESS],[AGE],[ID],[NAME],[SALARY] FROM ...

The result should be the output you expect.
```

Comment: The same cannot be applied for other tables. If its a generalized than it would be great.

Comment: Unfortunetly SQL itself doesn't care what order the columns come out.
You still need to write your query like the example i give to you. The last solution should be to create another table or maybe alter this one to get columns in the alphabetical order. Maybe on Oracle the manipulation could be possible using SYS but on SQL Server i don't guess that this could be possible